Finding the correlation of two related random variables
Problem:
Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be uncorrelated random variables. Find the covariance and correlation between $U_1 = Y_1 + Y_2$ and $U_2 = Y_1 - Y_2$ in terms of the
variances of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.
Answer:
Let $\sigma^2_1$ be the variance of $Y_1$. Let $\sigma^2_2$ be the variance of $Y_2$.
\begin{align*}
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(U_1 U_2) - E(U_1)E(U_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(( Y_1 + Y_2)( Y_1 - Y_2 )) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 + Y_2Y_1 - Y_1Y_2 - Y_2^2) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2) - (E(Y_1) + E(Y_2))( E(Y1) - E(Y_2)) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2) - E(Y_1)E(Y_1) + E(Y_2)E(Y_2 ) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2) - E(Y_2^2) - E(Y_1)E(Y_1) + E(Y_2)E(Y_2 ) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2) -  E(Y_1)E(Y_1) - ( E(Y_2^2) - E(Y_2)E(Y_2 ) )  \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &=  \sigma^2_1 - \sigma^2_2
\end{align*}
My answer for the $cov( U_1, U_2 ) $ matches the book.
Now we need to find the correlation. The general formula for correlation is:
$$ COR(x,y) = \dfrac{ cov(x,y)  }{\sigma_x \sigma_y} $$
\begin{align*}
COR( U_1, U_2 ) &=   \dfrac{ cov(U_1,U_2)  }{\sigma_{u_1} \sigma_{u_2} } \\
\sigma^2_{u_1} &= E(u_1^2) - \left( E(u_1)\right) ^2 \\
\sigma^2_{u_1} &= E((Y_1+Y_2)^2) - \left( E(Y_1+Y_2)\right) ^2 \\
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
$$ \dfrac{\sigma^2_1 - \sigma^2_2 }{ \sigma^2_1 + \sigma^2_2} $$
However, I do not know how to find it.

$$
    \sigma_{U_1}^2 = \text{Var}(U_1) = \text{Var}(Y_1 + Y_2) = \text{Cov}(Y_1 + Y_2, Y_1 + Y_2) = \text{Var}(Y_1) + \text{Var}(Y_2) + 2 \text{Cov}(Y_1, Y_2)
$$
Since $Y_1, Y_2$ are uncorrelated, $\text{Cov}(Y_1, Y_2) = 0$. Thus,
$$
   \sigma_{U_1}^2 = \text{Var}(Y_1) + \text{Var}(Y_2) = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2
$$
Apply the same way to compute $\sigma_{U_2}^2$ and obtain $\sigma_{U_2}^2 = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$
